# reading a set count of characters from the console input stream

Tags: c#, textbox, console, inputstream

I'm trying to make something like a textbox for a console application,
how to limit the `Console.In` to only read a defined count of characters from user inputs  ?

### **EDIT**

I can't go the `Readkey()` loop -way, i still need to interact with that box, like using the arrow keys to navigate left an right, Del or Backspace to edit the input and some some keys for validation. `ReadKey` is printing those key as a " " (space) and i can't rely on counting on how many key are pressed since **Overtyping** may occur (and in this project, we need overtyping ! )

Im thinking of something like reading from the buffer at a specified location and set the cursor to an another location when that field max lengh is reached. can it be done this way ?

what are my chances ? i really need your help

Comment: I think he means that he only wants the input to echo a particular number of characters (i.e. having the console mimic setting the `MaxLength` property on a `TextBox`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't set limitations on Console.ReadLine() etc. But you can make loop Console.ReadLine() for example and validate input in it.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious to see if it could be done, here is what I came up with:

```
    private static string ReadBox(int maxLen)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int pos = 0;
        bool done = false;      
        int start = Console.CursorLeft;

        while (!done)
        {
            var ki = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (ki.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    done = true;
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Delete:
                    // todo
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                    if (pos > 0)
                    {
                        pos -= 1;
                        sb.Remove(pos, 1);
                    }                                
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (pos > 0) pos -= 1;
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if (pos < sb.Length) pos += 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    if (ki.KeyChar >= ' ')  // simple filter
                    {
                        sb.Insert(pos, ki.KeyChar);
                        pos += 1;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.CursorLeft = start;
            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
            Console.CursorLeft = start + pos;                
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Note that we are not actually using the Console.In buffer here, it is bypassed. Oh, and I left out the feature that started it all, a maxlength. But you can easily implement that.

But if you're serious about this kind of UI, I would look around for a curses library, like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/) But it looks like it's for Mono, I'm not even sure if it will run on NET. Search around.

Comment: thanks, sure i've learned something from your code, but his not doing the job, the Backspace is not working and I'm having some trouble handling the INS and DEL keys, I need to have the same behavior when using Console.ReadLine(). I'm noe seeing any solution by using the ReadKey()

Comment: Did you notice the comment in the Delete case?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ReadKey` in a loop and pass `true` to prevent echo.

Comment: Actually you have pass (Intercept=) **true**. And handle cursor, backspace, delete etc

Comment: i've edited my post, but i still need the use backspace and delete keys, ReadKey() will only echo them or reject them